# NSFetchRequest: FetchBatchSize and Faulting Behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am new with Core Data, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Is there a way to set the fetchBatchSize property on an automatic fetch request generated by firing a fault by accessing an NSManagedObject relationship?

For instance, let's say I have a "Companies" entity and a "Employees" entity with a one-to-many relationship from "Companies" to "Employees". I make a fetch request to retrieve all the companies, then for one company I would like to load its employees.

The obvious way would be to do something like this :

```
NSSet *employees = [anyCompany employees];
```

But then, how do I set the fetchBatchSize property to ensure not to load too much data at the same time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `NSSet *employees = [anyCompany employees]` does not fetch the data, it returns a "relationship fault". Only when you access properties of an object in the set, a fault is fired and the properties of this object are fetched from the store if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fetchBatchSize` just defines how many records are going to be retrieved in one round trip to the persistent store. For example, if you have 1000 entries for one entity and your batch size is 20, a fetch request fetching all entries will actually execute 50 SQL statements.

It is clear that this is not very efficient depending on the context of your fetch. You can calibrate the fetch request with the batch size if memory becomes an issue, but in most cases you really do not have to care about it too much. Unnecessary multiple round trips to the store, however, will most likely affect performance.

So just use an expression like

```
aCompany.employees
```

liberally and let Core Data deal with the memory management. It will typically only retrieve the entities and attributes it actually needs for display or calculation.